# How to provide file content as scheme extension?

Tags: scheme

I've got

```
(define (compiler exp)
  (define (printer line) (display line) (newline))
  (init-generators)
  (let ((res (compile (append bootstrap (list exp)) function-res '())))
    (map printer c-string-list)
    (display bootstrap-c-code)
    (add-c-function 'startup '(env) res)
    (map (lambda (function) (map printer function) (newline)) c-function-list)
    'ok))
```

and I need

```
(define (compile file-name) 
    (compiler (load file-name)))
```

But it doesn't work this way. It's executing directly. How can I load it as expression? (exp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the `read` function, as opposed to `load`?  Without knowing more about the implementation you're using, I can only point to the [read](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_612) documentation from r5rs.  Use `open-input-file` to get a port from the filename, and then read from that port.

Answer (score 1):

What's the content of the file `file-name`? If it's an expression, `load` will execute it, for instance if `file-name` contains `(+ 1 1)`, `(load filename)` will return 2.

On the other hand, if `file-name` contains a list of symbols, they will be read as they are, for example if `file-name` contains `'(+ 1 1)` (notice the quote at the beginning), then `(load filename)` will return `(+ 1 1)`, which I'm guessing is what you mean by saying that you need to load it as an expression.

If you need to load several expressions inside the file, surround them with a quote and a begin in the file:

```
'(begin
  <your code here>
  )
```

Comment: content of file-name is just c++ code I need just get as string (but only now I understood it) and solved :)